# Validate uniqueness also on deleted documents with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, mongoid

I've got a rails application with a `User` model like the following one:

```rb
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Paranoia

  field :email, type: String
  index({ email: 1 }, { unique: true })

  validates :email, presence:true, uniqueness:true
end
```

That's my test:

```rb
describe User do
  it 'has an unique email' do
    first_user = Fabricate(:user, email: 'test@fundbase.com')
    first_user.valid?.should be_true # good
    first_user.save
    first_user.delete

    second_user = Fabricate(:user, email: 'test@fundbase.com')
    second_user.valid?.should be_true # good
    second_user.save

    first_user.restore
    first_user.valid?.should_not be_true # fail
  end
end
```

Here the last test fails. For some reason the uniqueness of the email field doesn't get checked. Any hints on how to force the validation on restore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a bug in the paranoia module (which is actually going to disappear in the next major version of Mongoid: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/extras.html#paranoia). If you need user account to be "resurrected", you may want to add your own boolean field such as "enabled" which you can set to false to disable an account.